# Как можно повысить скорость загрузки сайта на битрикс по гугл pagespeed?

Tags: битрикс

Как можно повысить скорость загрузки сайта на битрикс по гугл pagespeed   https://pvh-membrany.ru/?

Картинки сжимались, проводилась работа над джавасрипт тоже. Осталось вроде влияние гугл аналитики. Как ускорить загрузку страниц?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас на скриншоте всё написано, в каждой рекомендации этого инструмента есть соответствующая ссылка с возможным решением той или иной проблемы (если же не решение, то описание в какую сторону копать). У Вас ещё море работы по оптимизации и я бы сказал что серверную часть стоит рассматривать в последнюю очередь. Настройте кеширование статических ресурсов, измените формат изображений (желательно на webp и оптимизированный jpеg для сафари и т.д) и уменьшите количество запросов и Вы явно увидите разницу в результатах. Самое главное ОПТИМИЗИРУЙТЕ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ, они являются львиной долей трафика

Answer (score 0):

Ваш сайт довольно быстро загружается, не знаю что вы хотите получить, но тот же stackoverflow грузится дольше :D

**Варианты которые я вижу:**

1. Отказаться от CMS
2. Не верить тесту (он неадекватно оценивает)
3. Если заказчик прилип и хочет видеть сотку, а вы уже и так выжали всё что могли и сайт загружается быстрее чем заказчик отрывает рот, то вот статья для вас: https://vc.ru/services/103768-kak-nakruchivayut-100-ballov-na-google-pagespeed

**Update:** Для тех, кто считает, что PageSpeed Insights адекватно оценивает скорость загрузки сайта и на него можно смотреть:

1. Ему по барабану, что это может быть SPA (а таких сейчас много - react, vue, angular). Он будет считать, что ваш сайт работает медленно, просто потому, что при первой загрузке ваш сервер отправляет ему все файлы
2. Ему плевать что после загрузки frontend может происходить дозагрузка файлов с backend части, он это не учитывает
3. Он показывает неадекватные цифры. Например для stackoverflow в графе "отображение первого контента" стоит 3 секунды. Какие 3 секунды? У меня меньше секунды проходит. По вашему это адекватная оценка?
4. Он оценивает ТОЛЬКО время загрузки контента в браузере (написано в документации). Ему всё равно сколько отвечает сервер. Если будет приложение с server side rendering, где сервер рендерит страницу и отвечает 5 секунд, то гугл тест покажет 100 баллов. Ну а чё? В браузере же быстро грузится после получения и плевать сколько там клиент ждёт =)

Comment: Считаю что Ваши доводы относительно "довольно быстро загружается" и "он неадекватно оценивает" не соответствуют действительности, а также советы относительно заказчика, явно говорят о Вашем отношении к работодателю (если же Вы неуважительно относитесь к людям которые дают Вам работу, не стоит распространять этот пример на других). лично я не накручивал и смог добиться тех же 100%.

Comment: @noname2019 специально для вас обновил ответ и привёл аргументы, почему page speed test неадекватен. Попрошу заметить, к способу указанному в 3 пункте я предлагал переходить только после того, как вся оптимизация выполнена, больше делать нечего, а заказчик не понимает, что то, что показывает test speed бред и хочет сотку

Comment: Спорить с Вами бесполезно, да и не то это место где идут споры, хоть даже и в них рождается техническая истина для одного из нас) Но специально для Вас расскажу : 1) SPA тоже бывают разные, если Вы всё правильно организуете, PSI не будет говорить что SPA медленный, 2) Лично проверял, все ленивые и js подгрузки(для старых браузеров) изображений (после загрузки страницы) отлично находит и анализирует. 3) Это просто Ваше эмоциональное мнение... 4) Тоже проверял и  если сервер долго отвечает PSI 
 обязательно об этом говорит. Вы несёте откровенную чушь, извините за выражение.

Comment: @noname2019 1) нет фактов, что по вашему правильная реализация для SPA? 2) Допустим у нас есть SPA. С него идёт кроссдоменный запрос к backend за списком статей. Попробуйте искусственно сделать так, чтобы back отвечал 10 минут и вы увидите, что тест не учитывает этот запрос и покажет время отрисовки 3-10 секунд 3) Можете взять секундомер, если вы действительно считаете, что stackoverflow грузится 3 секунды 4) Я не знаю как вы там проверяли, но в документации самого теста написано обратное

Comment: 1) Не по моему, а по советам PSI, убрать лишний код и лишние запросы, уменьшить количество передаваемых по сети данных 2) Обязательно попробую 3) Это не обязательно, все инструменты уже давно созданы и внедрены в любимые ПО 4) Пересмотрел кучу доков к PSI, но не могу найти где же написано что он не учитывает доступность или скорость загрузки с других хостов ? Вы 2 раза ссылались на документацию, скиньте пожалуйста ссылку почитать (может я действительно ошибаюсь)

Comment: @noname2019 1) Наверное webpack который используется в большинстве SPA намного лучше знает как оптимизировать код и сделает это лучше pageSpeed? Даже если писать правильный код это не меняет сути. Первая загрузка SPA всегда будет дольше, потому что это SPA, а для pageSpeed каждая загрузка первая 3) Ну так проверьте =) 4) "FCP measures how long it takes the browser to render the first piece of DOM content" - показывает сколько нужно браузеру времени, чтобы срендерить первый контент. Я взял это тут: https://web.dev/first-contentful-paint/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown